# Taking the mean of certain columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data frame which looks like this:

| variable | 2000-1 | 2000-2 | 2000-3 | 2001-1 | 2001-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| Y | 6 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 5 |

How to I select columns which contain "2000" and those which contain "2001" and add new columns with the average of all values under Years 2000 and 2001?

Comment: have a look at [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Comment: kindly add your expected output dataframe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should post a minimal reproducible example, hence no tables, ... add your `dataframe` instead!. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) more details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can select columns by [`.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and then take the average by [`.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) on `axis=1`, as follows:

```
df['2000-Avg'] = df.filter(like='2000-').mean(axis=1)
df['2001-Avg'] = df.filter(like='2001-').mean(axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  variable  2000-1  2000-2  2000-3  2001-1  2001-2  2000-Avg  2001-Avg
0        X       4       5       6       7       8       5.0       7.5
1        Y       6       8      10       9       5       8.0       7.0
```

If you have multiple years to process, you can define the range of years, and then execute similar statement, as follows:

```
years = np.arange(2000, 2001+1)   # replace 2001 by the latest years, as appropriate

for year in years:
    df[f'{year}-Avg'] = df.filter(like=f'{year}-').mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to select only year columns then `groupby` each year and compute `mean`:

```
>>> df.join(df.filter(regex='\d{4}-[1-12]')
              .groupby(lambda x: x.split('-')[0], axis=1)
              .mean().add_suffix('-avg'))

  variable  2000-1  2000-2  2000-3  2001-1  2001-2  2000-avg  2001-avg
0        X       4       5       6       7       8       5.0       7.5
1        Y       6       8      10       9       5       8.0       7.0
```